# Netflix in Germany has no support for Linux

Tags: netflix, linux

Netflix is just recently available on Germany, so I happily created an account and when I tried to open a movie, I was welcomed with this message:

> Complete System Requirements
>
> To watch instantly, you''ll need a computer that meets the following
>   minimum requirements:
>
> - Windows
>
>   - Windows Vista or Windows 7
>   - Internet Explorer 8 or higher; or the latest version of Firefox; or the latest version of Chrome
>   - 1.2 GHz processor
>   - 512 MB RAM
> - Mac
>
>   - An Intel-based Mac with OS 10.4.11 or later
>   - Safari 4 or higher; or the latest version of Firefox; or the latest version of Chrome
>   - 1 GB RAM
> - Chrome OS
>
>   - A Google Chromebook or Chromebox running Chrome OS 29 or higher

I am running Linux Mint, so this is not good for me.

I seem to have read in some pages, there are ways to circumvent these restrictions, but they are in German, and I do not speak the language that well, despite living here.

Could anyone please help me set up the system?

Comment: @pnuts I think this is the right place.

Comment: If I recall, Linux support was just announced. It wouldn't surprise me at all for them to roll it out domestically first before opening it up to the world. I'll see if I can find the announcement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like Linux support is fully there, but it's getting close and, depending on what you're running, may already work for you.

Seen on [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2014/09/19/netflix-linux/):

> watching flicks in your favorite distro (be it Ubuntu, Mint or Arch) may finally come true. Paul Adolph from Netflix [posted a message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2014-September/015048.html) to Ubuntu developers, telling them that, "Netflix will play with Chrome stable in 14.02 if NSS version 3.16.2 or greater is installed."